# Error Occured During Restoration From Mysql Dump

Tags: mysql

```
Head of the dump shows this:
-- MySQL dump 10.13  Distrib 5.7.19, for osx10.11 (x86_64)
--
-- Host: localhost    Database: merchant
-- ------------------------------------------------------
-- Server version   5.6.37

/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8 */;
```

I am loading this dump on mysql 5.6.30 , Ubuntu 17.10 x86_64

ERROR at line 2142: ASCII '\0' appeared in the statement, but this is not allowed unless option --binary-mode is enabled and mysql is run in non-interactive mode. Set --binary-mode to 1 if ASCII '\0' is expected. Query: 'INSERT INTO `inventory_inventorylog` VALUES (51504,'1101000',1.000,'PE-209444-119',1,'910749','2018-02-13 07:40:10.718324',4,9444,NULL,'[{\"count\": \"1\", \"obj_id\": 132059}, {\"count\": \"1\", \"obj_id\": 132061}, {\"count\": \"1\", \"obj_id\": 132063}, {\"count\": \"1\", \"obj_id\": 132066}, {\"................

I tried enabling binary mode but it didn't work . tables upto inventory_inventorylog get loaded only

```
[~/Documents/newer dump]$file mysql15March.sql 
mysql15March.sql: ASCII text, with very long lines
```

Comment: try to get dump file with .dmp extension instead of .sql

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using '>' parameter in mysqldump is generally discouraged because it first sends it to the terminal stdout and then to the output file , which can lead to character encoding problems, especially if the terminal has different encoding set beside utf-8.

use this instead

```
mysqldump <host> <user> <pwd> <dbname> -r yourfile.sql
```